# AttributeError: module 'torchtext.datasets' has no attribute 'text_classification'

Tags: python, nlp, pytorch, torchtext

```
agnews_train, agnews_test = torchtext.datasets.text_classification.DATASETS["AG_NEWS"](root="./datasets")
```

after running above line I am geting attribute error.

> AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
>  in 
> ----> 1 agnews_train, agnews_test = torchtext.datasets.text_classification.DATASETS"AG_NEWS"

AttributeError: module 'torchtext.datasets' has no attribute 'text_classification'

Answer (score 0):

You are probably just using a different version. What you want is:

```
agnews_train, agnews_test = torchtext.datasets.AG_NEWS(root='./datasets', split=('train', 'test'))
```

[Documentation](https://pytorch.org/text/stable/datasets.html#id2)